# SendMessage WM_SETTEXT issue

Tags: c++, sendmessage

Ok this is probably a noob issue... probably a really newb issue lol, but I am a newb so here it goes:

I want to write down the following text in an edit control:
C:\Documents and Settings\Blah\Desktop\myText.txt

I wrote the following code:

```
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"C:\Documents and Settings\Blah\Desktop\myText.txt");
```

And it does write in the edit control, however it doesn't write exactly what I wanted, rather it writes:

C:Documents and SettingsBlahDesktopmyText.txt

which is everything except the "\" symbol.... Now I have looked everywhere for a solution but haven't found one cause I am a newb.

Question:: What do I have to write in the fourth parameter so that the "\" can also be included?

Comment: Backslashes. They must be escaped.

Comment: What do you mean they must be escaped? I need to write them in the edit box, so what would I include in the (LPARAM)"what do I include here" in order for the backslashes to appear?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi :D. I'm not going to make a fool of myself by trying to work out the exact syntax here without preview (original comment with unescaped backslashes deleted, for anyone who missed it).

Comment: @computerWizard, you would do nothing in that case. Backslashes only have to be escaped in literals.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi (it confused me because I doubled one but not the other, and they both wound up looking the same)

Comment: @dlf, for what it's worth I tried too but did not succeed (markdown gets in the way). Let's try again: `\\ `.

Comment: hahah this was kinda funny. Simple solution but lots of discussion :P. Thanks to all you guys btw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [escape your backslashes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx):

```
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Blah\\Desktop\\myText.txt");
```

Comment: Missed one at the end...

Comment: I did, thanks. Good eye.

Comment: awesome man, your the man. Simple yet effective answer.

Comment: I think String literal would be an even better choice with `@` as in `SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM) @"C:\Documents and Settings\Blah\Desktop\myText.txt");`

Comment: @Antony both yield the same string literal. It really comes down to personal preference.